# Problems running FFprobe with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, terminal, ffprobe

I am fairly new to Ruby and programming, less than a year experience. This is ruby 1.9.3 and the newest ffmpeg for Ubuntu from FFmpeg. Files I am using are basic .avi, some v210 .mov, other quicktime/finalcutpro types of files.

I am trying to write an automated probing tool that will help lessen the manual work load for me when I start testing with and dealing with lots of media files. Basically the script goes through a directory and probes each file, extracting the info I need, and writes it out to csv.

Currently, everytime I run it, the actual capture on command line is failing.

```
def prober(file)
  @the_file = file
  stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3("ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -      show_format -show_streams #{@the_file}")
  STDERR.puts stderr
  if status.success?
    out = stdout
  else
    STDERR.puts "There was a problem, please try again."
  end
  @raw_output = JSON.parse(out)
end
```

I don't know if it is something to do with how I am running the command (I don't really fully understand I/O streams), or something with ffprobe. When it does make it past the probe it is returning @raw_output as nil, which causes JSON parsing to puke, or my other methods for splitting and parsing the metadata fail on nil.

Any help at all would great, I have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks! I can provide more code if needed for clarification,.

Answer (score 0):

After the holidays I came back fresh and found the problem. The filepath string needs to have quotes around it when fed to the stdin for ffprobe, but when I aggregated the files it stripped the quotes. The fix? add quotes around the filepath in the string.

I hope this helps someone, apparently I am the only person in the whole internet to have this problem.